# How to use google ml kit face pose estimation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, pose-estimation

Previously I used Firebase ML kit for flutter to get user head position left, right, up and down in my applicatoin. It was easy then but now I can't find the way to implement google ml kit for same implementation.

```
  final FaceExpressionProvider _expressionProvider = FaceExpressionProvider();
  final FaceExpressionUtils _expressionVerifier = FaceExpressionUtils();
```

```
void _expressionListener() {
    final Face face = _expressionProvider.face;
    if (_controller == null) _controller = _expressionProvider.cameraController;
    var state = _expressionVerifier.process(face);
    _instruction = _instructionMapper(state);
    if (state == Instructions.VerificationComplete) {
      _captureImage();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
```

```
FaceMovementInstruction _instructionMapper(Instructions instruction) {
    final instructions = [
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).faceNotFound.toUpperCase(),
          "facenotfound"),
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).lookLeft.toUpperCase(), "lookleft"),
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).lookRight.toUpperCase(), "lookright"),
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).smilePlease.toUpperCase(), "smile"),
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).verified.toUpperCase(), "verified"),
      FaceMovementInstruction(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).error.toUpperCase(), "error"),
    ];
    switch (instruction) {
      case Instructions.ShowFace:
        return instructions[0];
      case Instructions.LookLeft:
        return instructions[1];
        break;
      case Instructions.LookRight:
        return instructions[2];
        break;
      case Instructions.SmilePlease:
        return instructions[3];
        break;
      case Instructions.AnalyzingResults:
        break;
      case Instructions.VerificationComplete:
        return instructions[4];
        break;
    }
    return instructions[5];
  }
```

i'd used import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart'; library